# Cell file resolution differs from current region in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, error, resolution

## Error

```
r.terraflow elevation=cdnh43e_v1@user1 filled=cdnhfill direction=cdnhdir 
swatershed=cdnhsink accumulation=cdnhacc tci=cdnhtci
```

> ERROR: cell file cdnh43e_v1 resolution differs from current region
>   (Fri Oct 03 13:32:11 2014) Command finished (0 sec)

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure the region settings in GRASS before running any raster calculations. The region settings define for example the resolution of the output raster. In raster based calculations where there are multiple inputs it is important to work with the same resolutions, so the input rasters are in total cover. Also, resampling is a totally useless overcomputation as the output data physically can't contain more information if it is a derivative of the input data, even on finer resolution.

As `r.terraflow` is designed to be "able to process efficiently very large terrains" ([GRASS GIS manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.terraflow.html), 2014.), it won't deal with differences in the resolution.

The examples in the manual states that the easiest way to achieve the same region settings as your input raster, run the `g.region rast=your_data` command in the GRASS terminal. In your case the command is `g.region rast=cdnh43e_v1@user1`.

Comment: Yes, for general hints see also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region